# How to use logical operations result in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

(I have solved this problem in a different way, I just came back to revisit it.)

A few days ago, I wanted to run multiple functions, and check if all of it ran successfully. For this reason, I tried to run it in a way:

```
<p id="example"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = true && true;
</script>
```

Which ran as expected, the "true" appeared in the p. So I made it more exotic by:

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = function x() {return true} && true;
```

As before, it worked as intended (Actually, I declared the function outside the command, I just fused them to save space.), however, after that, I got some weird results:

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = function x() {return true} && function y() {return true};
```

What was weird, the result I got inside the p was: `function y() {return true};`
I somehow received the rest of the command after the && part. Normally I should've got the result of the function, not the whole function. Can anyone explain why did it happen?

Comment: Apparently I made 2 mistakes, but I can't accept both answers. Declaring only functions but not calling them, and using && the wrong way. Thanks Alexandru-Ionut Mihai and Gerardo Furtado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why did it happen?

You only declare the `body` of the **functions** but you need to `invoke/call` them in order to find out the **returned** values.

You should use `IIFE` in order to use `self-invoking` functions.

Read more about [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```js
//document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = true && true;
//document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = function x() {return true} && true;
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = (function x() {return true})() && (function y() {return true})();
```

```html
<p id="example"></p>
```

Comment: (Addendum: if the first function is false, the second will not run at all, since && simply returns the first part. ie. `FALSE && function x() {important calculations}()` the first part is returned instantly without running the second function. Reasons explained in the other answers.)

Answer (score 2):

`function y() {return true}` merely ***declares*** a function, it never *calls* the function. So the two values you're comparing with `&&` are two function objects, not the values those functions return would you call them. Function objects are *truthy*. The `&&` operator doesn't return `true` or `false`, it returns one of its operands (the first if the first is *falsey*, else the second). So the result of `<function object> && <function object>` is the second function object.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) about JavaScript AND operator is very clear:

> **Operator**: Logical AND (&&)
>
> **Usage**: expr1 && expr2
>
> **Description**: Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2.

So, for instance, if you have two strings:

```js
console.log("Dog" && "Cat")
```

The second one will be returned.

In your example, the functions are truthy. Therefore, the second one is returned:

```js
console.log(function x() {return true} && function y() {return true})
```